# Add Column and Append Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of URLS for CSV files and a list of names, within a for loop I need to convert each CSV to a DataFrame and add a column containing the name at the same index in the list of names.

I can successfully download each CSV and create a data frame that is then appended to a new data frame, but having issue adding the column in the same iteration.

Below is what I currently have.

```
        for url, name in zip(url_list, name_list):

            df.append(pd.read_csv(url))

            df['Name'] = name

            complete_df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index = True)
```

This gives an error of

form_dfs['Name'] = name
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: please also include where you have defined the data frame. It looks like an error in definition.

Comment: you should post full code: *form_dfs* makes no sense related to the code. The error you get is because you use it as a dict instead of a list

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to input a string to column which is not legal.Do you need to add same name to whole column? 
 If that is the case you need to do following:

```
df['Name']=pd.Series([name for i in range(len(df))])
```

If you want something else,please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your code is attempting to index a list with a string. Instead, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add a series in-line:

```
df = []
for url, name in zip(url_list, name_list):
    df.append(pd.read_csv(url).assign(Name=name)

complete_df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

An alternative method is to use a list comprehension:

```
df = [pd.read_csv(url).assign(Name=name) for url, name in zip(url_list, name_list)]
complete_df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```